# Jquery Logic - Cloning div and changing the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic

I've seemingly got this to work [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/rdgk714a/4/).

```
var addId = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
var target = $(this).closest("#groupcontainer");// create var to clone
target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target);   // clone and insert after
var gc = addId++;   //increase addId by 1 to append to "groupcontainer" id
groupcontainer.id = "groupcontainer" + gc; // add 1 
alert(groupcontainer.id); //to see new id

});
```

As far as I can tell, the id's are changing appropriately after cloning.  The reason I am doing this is because each `#groupcontainer` created will need to be unique (I think), as I'll be adding them up into a final total amount.

Questions:

1. Does my logic make sense or is there a more efficient way to do this?
2. Will I be able to reference these new id's later on to sum them up?

Seems to me like I can but I'm not sure.

Comment: `this.id = "groupcontainer" + gc;` - This assigns the ID to the button.

Comment: no need for ID's...they just get complicated when adding/removing rows...use classes instead. Within event handlers you simply traverse within that specific module instance

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Edit make more sense?

Comment: If you use this method, you can find all of your containers back by using `for(var i = 1; $('#groupcontainer' + i).length > 0; i++){ var container = $('#groupcontainer' + i);}`

Comment: @charlietfl - My logic here was I'll need to reference a div inside `groupcontainer` later for a total sum and thought each one should be unique.  No good?

Comment: generally easier to traverse rows ... it's a pain to try to manage incremental ID's